# Is there a way to style the last row of a DataGrid to automatically consume all remaining height (ala VerticalAlignment="Stretch")?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, vertical-alignment

Setting the VerticalAlignment on the cell contents didn't work.  I think this is because the cell itself needs that.